# Окрашивание заднего фона картинки

Tags: изображения, photoshop

Создал следующую картинку (вернее просто изменил текст на Дигитал Электроникс). Как поменять белый цвет фона картинки на подходящий цвет или рисунок (изображение) (конкретно с указанием инcтрументов фотошопа)?

Я новичок, поэтому прошу меня не банить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Выберите этот инструмент и выделите им весь фон и замените его на свой цвет.

P.S Я знаю, вопрос задан давно.